# How I can Track application spend Time in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to track all Application usage time and all the link those I am open in safari Browser.

Is that Feasible in iOS or not?

Comment: No, not feasible. Luckily.

Comment: If you want to track your app usage and links opened through your app, then you can track. GoogleAnalytics is one of the best option.

Comment: Do you want to track some of the user calls too while your at it ?

Comment: Kindly check qustodio application on app Store. we can track time of each applciation. its Feasible but I do not how?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If by "all application usage time" you mean time that a user spends using apps *other than your own* on their device, then no. iOS is secure by design and explicitly prevents apps being able to fish around or track what a user is doing outside their own sandbox. The same goes for tracking links.

If you mean tracking usage in *your* apps, then the answer is of course yes because now you're simply talking about analytics; there are numerous programmatic and third-party ways.

Comment: I want to track each application and Safari History. Kindly check qustodio application on app Store.

Comment: Kindly check the reviews for the Qustodio app on the App Store; it's nothing but a portal to a web site because, as outlined above, tracking usage of native apps is forbidden by design.